# Rails 4 / Turbolinks / jQuery: keydown event not being triggered on newly inserted element?

Tags: jquery, turbolinks

I'm on Rails 4 using the jquery-turbolinks gem. I have a link that when clicked, will add a input field to the DOM using jQuery:

`$(".add_color").html("<input id='add_color_text_field' type='text' name='color' placeholder='Provide a color name'>");`

However, the jQuery in my application.js is not firing for this newly generated input:

```
    $(function() {


        $('#add_color_text_field').keydown(function(e) {
            alert("here");
        });

       ...
```

This works when I change the selector to point an already existing input field on the initial page load, so I'm sure it works. What do I need to change to my jQuery to make my newly generated DOM element works with turbolinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the [`jquery-turbolinks` gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks). It is easily installed:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

run `bundle install` and edit the Javascript manifest:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
```

and should solve your problem.

Please read the note on binding to `$(document)` at the end of the github page (do not bind inside `$(function () {...});` as those events will be executed multiple times then).

Comment: Okay this worked: `$(document).on('keydown', '#add_color_text_field', function() { alert("here"); });` when I took it out of my $(function() {...}); block. So where should I put the rest of my jQuery? Should they all look like `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() { something });`?

Comment: You only need to put the ones which already bind to `document` outside of the global function call. If you simply bind something to an element like `$('#example').on('submit', function () {...});` this can stay inside of `$(function () {...});` and should work with the jquery-turbolinks gem.

Comment: Nice. so what you're saying is that I have to use `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {...})...` for jQuery that target elements that don't exist on the initial page load?

Comment: There is a difference between `$(document).on('...', 'selector', function () {})` and `$('selector').on('...', function () {})` (first one applies to all elements, second one only to elements which exist on initial page creation). The first ones need to be put outside of the global call structure. The second ones can stay where they are. Which one you want to use depends on your application, not on the gem or turbolinks.